# Finding the predecessor / successor of a list item in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am having a hard time translating idea from Lisp to Prolog. I did find out how to find the predecessor and successor in Lisp but I am having hard time implementing the same idea in Prolog. I am very poor with the syntax. Please help me out.

Sample queries:

```
?- predecessor(b,[a,b,c],P).
P = a.                          % expected result

?- successor(b,[a,b,c],S).
S = c.                          % expected result
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a DCG approach:

```
pred(X, P) --> stuff, [P,X], stuff.
succ(X, S) --> stuff, [X,S], stuff.
stuff --> [] | [_], stuff.

predecessor(X, L, P) :- phrase(pred(X, P), L).
successor(X, L, P) :- phrase(succ(X, S), L).
```

Sporadic trials:

```
| ?- predecessor(a, [a,1,2,a,3], L).

L = 2 ? ;

no
| ?- predecessor(X, [1,2,3,2,5], 2).

X = 3 ? a

X = 5

no
| ?- successor(a, [a,1,2,a,3], L).

L = 1 ? a

L = 3

no
| ?- successor(X, [1,2,3,2,5], 2).

X = 1 ? a

X = 3

no
| ?-
```

Per @false's comments, the implementation can be tidied up a bit:

```
predecessor(X, L, P) :- phrase((..., [P,X], ...), L).
successor(X, L, S) :- phrase((..., [X,S], ...), L).
... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

With the same test results.

Comment: There are better names for "stuff" like `... /0`

Comment: @false yes, I've seen you use that and I like it.

Comment: I got it from: David B. Searls, Investigating the Linguistics of DNA with Definite Clause Grammars. NACLP 1989.

Comment: Other issue: you can avoid the pred//2, succ//2 intermediary definition, by  putting the body into phrase/2

Comment: @false oh, nice, I didn't realize that (either of those two last points).

Answer (score 2):

If `X` is the second element of the list, the predecessor (`Y`) is the first:

```
pred( X, [Y,X|_], Y).
```

Otherwise, look for the predecessor in the rest of the list:

```
pred( X, [_|Z], Y ) :- pred( X, Z, Y ).
```

If `X` is the first element of the list, the successor (`Y`) is the second:

```
succ( X, [X,Y|_], Y).
```

Otherwise, look for the successor in the rest of the list:

```
succ( X, [_|Z], Y ) :- succ( X, Z, Y ).
```

Comment: (+1) I would say, "*a* successor" or "*a* predecessor" rather than *the* since there may be more than one solution, which these predicates will find.

Comment: Yep, I figured. The OP may not even have been thinking about the case of more than one solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was opting for a very hard attempt which is to reverse the list and find the predecessor of the item. Your attempt is very helpful and easy! You are awesome !

Answer (score 2):

You could ...

- Use the built-in `append/3`:

  ```
  predecessor( X , L , P ) :- append( _ , [P,X|_] , L ) .

  successor(   X , L , S ) :- append( _ , [X,S|_] , L ) .
  ```
- Roll your own:

  ```
  predecessor( X , [P,X|_] , P ) .
  predecessor( X , [_|T]   , P ) :- predecessor(X,T,P) .

  successor(   X , [X,S|T] , S ) .
  successor(   X , [_|T]   , S ) :- successor(X,T,S) .
  ```